# How to section UITableView with FirebaseTableViewDataSource in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm using FirebaseTableViewDataSource to keep my Firebase Database data in sync, as explained in the FirebaseUI documentation.
However, I'd like to section my data into multiple sections.
Is there a way of doing this? Here's my code so far:

```
fileprivate var dataSource: FirebaseTableViewDataSource!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let url = Constants.GetUrl()
    {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(url)
        databaseRef.keepSynced(true)

        self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: databaseRef, nibNamed: "MyTableViewCell", cellReuseIdentifier: "myCell", view: self.tableView)

        self.tableView.dataSource = self.dataSource

        self.dataSource.populateCell
            {
                (anyCell: UITableViewCell, obj: NSObject) -> Void in

                self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "myCell")

                let cell = anyCell as! MyTableViewCell
                let snap = obj as! FIRDataSnapshot  

                cell.myLabel?.text = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "url").value as? String
                // how to put this cell into another section?
                let sectionNum = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "section").value
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: That's an open feature request. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/8

Comment: Thank you. I'd looked there and thought it had been merged into master. Seems it hasn't. D'oh!